# How Shared Preferences in Android Works?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I came across an Android Question as follows. The result is confusing me.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("1", "2"); // Storing string
        editor.putString("3", "4 "); // Storing string
        editor.commit();
        System.out.println("pref.getString() = " + pref.getString("2","3"));
```

> Answer:  pref.getString() = 3.

How does the shared preference prints this value ? Can someone please explain this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SharedPreference object does not print anything.

The sharedPreference stores data in key-value pairs in an xml file named MyPref in your case:

```
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
```

You put the value you want to store by calling the putXX method on the editor object obtained from the pref object by calling edit() on it:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

> ** putXX means put[some kind of primitive data] like int float String.

When you call putString you supply a key as the first parameter and the String value in this case as the second parameter:

```
editor.putString("1", "2"); // Storing string
editor.putInt("myInt", 2); // Storing integer
```

The commit method writes the data.

```
editor.commit();
```

The getString retrieve a string value for a key given as the first parameter and if they are no entry a default value returned which is the second parameter in this case "3":

```
String myValue = pref.getString("2","3")
```

The printing performed by calling:

```
 System.out.println(myValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to `get...()` is the shared preferences key. The second argument is the default value to return in case there's no value by that key.

Assuming no other code has put a value with key `"2"` in this shared preferences file, the default value of `"3"` is returned when calling `pref.getString("2","3")`.

Answer (score 0):

editor.putString("1", "2") - first argument is KEY, second argument is value. 
pref.getString("2","3") - first argument is KEY, second argument is Default value (in case if such key isn't present).

In your case you've put two strings - 2 and 4 in keys 1 and 3 accordingly. 
When you are trying to read string with key 2 - it is missing. So default value (3) is printed

P.s. you are using keys very similar to values - Strings containing numbers. Just put more readable keys and thing will get clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Android has a page that it's very clean. [Shared Preferences getString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

This method has two parameters :

> key

The name of the preference to retrieve.

> defValue

Value to return if this preference does not exist.
This value may be **null**.

So if you have this in your `SharedPreferences`

```
editor.putString("1", "2"); // Storing string
editor.putString("3", "4 "); // Storing string
```

And you are doing : `pref.getString("2","3")`

You are looking for the `SharedPreferences` key with a value of "2", and if it doesn't find anything you'll get "3" as a default value.